# Is there any way we can change the index location of an element present in a list?

Tags: python, list

Example:-
list1 = [ a, b, c, d, e] has index location 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
Can we make the index locations for list1 -2, -1, 0, 1, 2

Comment: Index is how you access elements. not some value for the elements.

Comment: Can you provide the intended output of `list1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists are only indexable via positive integers (negatives have a special behavior to begin looking from the back of the list) and have a contiguous range up to the size of the list.

If you want to index by other means, either use a dictionary, or create a helper method to do this translation for you. Alternatively you could subclass the list (but this is the most complex and has a lot of corner cases to consider):

Dictionary solution.

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
list1 = {i - 2: v for i, v in enumerate(list1)} 
print(list1[-2])
```

```
a
```

Helper method solution:

```
def fetch_val(data, i):
    return data[i + 2]

fetch_val(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'], -2)
```

```
a
```

Override the list class:

```
class SpecialList(list):
    def __init__(self, start, *args, **kwargs):
        self.start = start
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return super().__getitem__(item - self.start)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key - self.start, value)


list1 = SpecialList(-2, ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
print(list1[-2])
```

```
a
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by:-

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
re_arrange_order = [-2, -1, 0, 1, 2]
for i in range(len(list1)):
    list1[i] = list1[re_arrange_order[i]]
print(list1)
```